# Query passar parâmetro null

Tags: delphi, firebird

Consigo passar o valor `is null` ou `is not null` através de uma Query? 
Exemplo no SQL:

```
select * from tb_teste where tb_teste.data_hora :PARAMETRO;
```

No Delphi:

```
Query.ParamByName('PARAMETRO').value = 'is not null';
```

ou

```
Query.ParamByName('PARAMETRO').value = 'is null';
```

Obs: o campo data_hora é um Timestamp, estou utilizando banco Firebird.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente você quer listar OU os registros com campo nulo OU os não-nulos, certo? O parâmetro nunca vai ser uma data cujo valor será aplicado no filtro da query.

Se é este o caso eu faria o seguinte:

Na query:

```
select * from tb_teste where 
(
    (:param = 'nulos' and tb_teste.data_hora is null ) 
 or (:param = 'preenchidos' and tb_teste.data_hora is not null)
);
```

Na unit:

```
Query.ParamByName('param').AsString = 'nulos';
```

ou

```
Query.ParamByName('param').AsString = 'preenchidos';
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim dentro da query:

```
select * from xpto where 1=1
and ((parametro = :parametro) or (parametro = -1))
```

ai quando for null vc passa -1

Answer (score 0):

Você precisara fazer algumas adaptações para conseguir, no formato atual que deseja NÃO é possível, pois:

`select * from tb_teste where tb_teste.data_hora FALTA_OPERADOR :PARAMETRO;`

Falta o operador, ou seja, ao executar esta consulta já possuirá erro de sql -104.

O que você pode fazer é definir uma string para substituição, penso em algo como:

```
if alguma_coisa then
  vTemp := 'is not null'
else
  vTemp := 'is null';
```

`vSQL := select * from tb_teste where tb_teste.data_hora &Troca&
 vSQL := vSQL.Replace('&Troca&', vTemp);`

Answer (score 0):

Se for com as Querys do FireDac dá, usando as macros em vez dos params
Na query usa

```
select * from tb_teste where tb_teste.data_hora !PARAMETRO;
```

e no codigo

```
Query.MacroByName('PARAMETRO').value = 'is not null';
```

Se der erro valida o tipo da macro na query, eu uso mdRaw mas presumo que tambem dá com mdString

Answer (score 0):

Como carregar parâmetros "nulos" em Query de Insert no Delphi

```delphi
Insert into tabela (campostr, campoint, campocur, campodat) Values (:vstr, :vint, :vcur, :vdat);

ParamByName('vstr').DataType := ftString;  

if varstrnull then ParamByName('vstr').Clear 
else ParamByName('vstr').AsString := 'string';

ParamByName('vint').DataType := ftInteger;

if varintnull then ParamByName('vint').Clear 
else ParamByName('vint').AsInteger := 1;

ParamByName('vcur').DataType := ftCurrency;

if varcurnull then ParamByName('vcur').Clear 
else ParamByName('vcur').AsCurrency := 1,25;

ParamByName('vdat').DataType := ftDate;

if vardatnull then ParamByName('vdat').Clear 
else ParamByName('vdat').AsDate := now;
```

obs.: Incluir a use DB.